# C printf func.. not prints all characters (printf or fileRead error )

Tags: c, printf

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(void) {
    char buff[8192] = { 0, };
    int len = 0;
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    int size = 0;

    fopen_s(&fp, "lenovoLaptopNews2.txt", "rt");

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    
    printf("len: %d\n", len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 1)
        buff[i] = fgetc(fp);
    
    //fread(buff, 1, 5131, fp);
    /*func(buff); printf("%s\n", buff);
    len = strlen(buff);
    printf("len:%d\n", len);
    printf("%s\n",buff);*/

    printf("%s\n", buff);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

I try to read the contents of the "LenovoLaptopNews.txt"
and save the contents to the buff variable.
and then print this by using printf("%s ... ",buff...);
but it doesn't print all characters and stops...
i don't know how to fix this issue..
plz help me ..

file contents are below ..

- filename : "lenovoLaptopNews2.txt"
- fileLen: 5131
- contents:

> Global innovation leader Lenovo is refreshing its suite of business PCs by releasing new ones equipped with AMD Ryzen processors for companies who wish to arrange a more robust work-from-home (WFH) setup. These are fully optimized with enhanced remote work capabilities and designed to take business computing at home to the next level with their faster processing power, anywhere-anytime productivity, and enterprise-level security features.
> Lenovo releases AMD-powered business laptops to boost WFH experience
> ThinkPad T14
> “Since the previous launch, the AMD Ryzen lineup has garnered nothing but praise from the tech industry for its efficient and fast processing speed even when used simultaneously for several intensive tasks. With work-from-home becoming the new normal work arrangement, we decided to integrate these powerful processors in our business solutions portfolio to further empower the remote workforce since they can significantly elevate the capabilities of our business laptops under different business environments,” said Michael Ngan, Lenovo Philippines President and General Manager.
> AMD Ryzen processors’ efficient yet powerful computing power is made possible through its “Zen” microarchitecture, which contains multiple cores and threads to do the computational heavy lifting. This allows the Ryzen processors to carry several of the distinct sets of commands and responses to calculate and render graphics, run software, and more, to make them the ideal processors for general office application, video conferencing, real-time analytics, code compilation, and 3D video rendering.
> Meanwhile, the AMD Ryzen™ processors with PRO technologies not only come equipped with the multi-core and thread setup but also possess enterprise-level security features to safeguard sensitive information through its GuardMI technology. This features AMD Memory Guard to provide real-time encryption of system memory to help protect against physical theft, and AMD Secure Boot,a program that helps prevent unauthorized software and malware from taking over critical system functions and blocks malicious code and unauthorized software from loading during startup.
> Workhorse business laptops
> Designed for multitasking professionals, the powerhouse ThinkPad T14 is capable of running a wide variety of business programs ranging from simple to those with heavy workloads with the device’s up to AMD Ryzen 7 Pro 4750U processor with 8 cores and 16 threads, up to 32GB DDR4-3200 memory, and up to 1TB PCIeNVMe SSD storage. The T14 can also last for up to 14hrs with its 50Wh battery.
>
> The ThinkPad X13, on the other hand, is suited for highly mobile modern professionals with its ultraportable weight of only 1.28kg and 16.9mm thinness. Further bolstering the X13’s capabilities while on the go is its 48Wh battery that can last up to 12.8 hours of use, with Rapid Charge support that provides 80% battery capacity in just an hour of charging. It also comes with an array of ports, including USB 3.2 Gen 1 and USB 3.2 Type-C with Power Delivery support which allows for faster charging. Powering the X13 is an up toAMD Ryzen 7 Pro 4750U processor with 8 cores and 16 threads, up to 1TB PCIeNVMe SSD storage, and a whopping up to 32GB DDR4 memory option.
> Both the ThinkPad T14 and X13 come with integrated AMD Radeon Graphics and up to Windows 10 Pro OS, which unlocks several features for business. The keyboards of the two devices possess Unified Communications support which optimizes functions such as making calls, instant messaging, and video collaboration by making them accessible in just a click of a button. During breaks, the two devices also become a handy tool for entertainment providing premium audio playback with their Dolby Audio Speaker System and clear video through their Full High Definition 1920x1080 IPS Anti-glare display with a 16:9 aspect ratio.
> Enterprise-level security and durability
> For added security, Lenovo equipped both the ThinkPad T14 and X13 with its ThinkShield suite for comprehensive end-to-end security. Some of its features include the dTPM 2.0 chip which encrypts sensitive information and a Touch Fingerprint Reader for biometric access. Buyers can also opt to have the PrivacyGuard security offering that warns users if someone is looking at their screen.Furthermore, both devices come with the legendary durability that Lenovo devices are known for. They have been tested against extreme conditions, including shock, vibration, hinge life, fan reliability, operating temperature, and pressure.
> Prices of the ThinkPad T14 and ThinkPad X13 depend on the configuration chosen by the buyer. Customers may also purchase accessories like the ThinkPad USB-CDock, USB-C Travel Hub, and USB 3.0 Secure HDD 1TBseparately.Devices and accessories may be purchased through authorized Lenovo retail partners and their respective online stores. For more information on the devices and tips on how to choose the right work technology for your company, contact Lenovo at https://www.facebook.com/lenovophilippines/ or visit the website at https://www.lenovo.com/ph/en/.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", buff);` is for printing _strings_.  `buff[]` is not a _string_ as it lacks a _null character_.

Comment: i want to print char array characters, but it stops..

Comment: Use `printf("%.*s\n", len, buff);` to print a character array and limit printing length.

Comment: I tried it but  same result ... what is the problem? i'm so curious TT

Comment: "but it doesn't print all characters"-->  After printing, make sure any buffered data is also printed with a following `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: i also added fclose(fp) and fflush(stdout)  but there's nothing changed.. i'm using visual studio2019.  is there any problem with vs2019?? i 'm so desperate TT

Comment: "but it doesn't print all characters and stops" --> what did it stop on?  Are you sure the file is an ASCII text one?

Comment: After the `for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 1)` loop what is the value of `i`?  Note that `strlen(buf)` is UB as `buf[]` is not a _string_.

Comment: okay i'll try it .. i'm so burnt out... thank u for helping me ...

Comment: oh my god!! i solved it.  the problem was  that i saved the file in UTF-8.  i fixed this to ANSI mode and then it works fine.  very thank you !!  i'm curious that why this happens.. LOL

Comment: @debug0x1231 Congratz on finding the solution! Please consider posting your solution as an answer and then accepting it.

Comment: @debug0x1231 I'd suggest that until you know why code "works" now, the root problem is not solved.

Comment: there are several other problems in the OPs posted code, like the function: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.   Suggest allocating a large buffer, say 1024 bytes, then in a loop: calling `fgets()` to read a single line from the file, and printing out that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have always the same problem after the answer to @user3629249, I give you this method for open and read, save the content file in char *.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int files_open(char const *path)
{
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY); // open file in read only

    if (fd < 0) {
        write(2, "ERROR: failed open file\n", 24);
    }
    return (fd);
}

char *read_files(struct stat *file_info, char *path)
{
    int fd = files_open(path);
    stat(path, file_info); // fill stat struct
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (file_info->st_size + 1));
    int a = read(fd, buffer, file_info->st_size);

    if (a < 0) // read failed
       exit(84) // leave the program and return an error
    buffer[file_info->st_size] = '\0';
    return (buffer);
}

void main(void)
{
    struct stat info;
    char *data = read_files(&info, "YOUR PATH");
    printf("%s", data);
    free(data);
}
```

In this code I use `open` for open file and recup the file descriptor. After recovering the **fd**, I fill my **stat** structure for know how many characters I have to read, and malloc the buffer. finally I use read function where I save each characters to my file in buffer and I return **buffer**.

man stat: http://www.linux-france.org/article/man-fr/man2/stat-2.html

man open: http://www.linux-france.org/article/man-fr/man2/open-2.html

man read: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to saving textfile in utf-8 mode.

Just save it in ANSI mode and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Please don't yell by using all-caps. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

*Why does the call to `printf()` stop printing early?*

because UTF8 can have '0x00' bytes in it. and `%s` in a `printf()` statement stops outputting when it encounters a `0x00` byte

That (above) problem can (usually) be overcome by using the `L` modifier on the data